# Book compilation taking forever, is standalone the culprit?

Tags: compiling, standalone, tikz-external

I have a book with a very large preamble (lots of commands, packages, etc.). When I comment all chapters but one, compilation takes the expected amount of time. However, when I try to compile the entire book the compilation time takes absurdly many hours! Because I have tons of figures and I use tikz, I opted for tikzexternal to prevent recreating the figures. However, when compiling the entire book, the first pass takes forever anyways. I'm trying to do everything in my power to speedup compilation. So I have the following questions:

1. Most of the figures I create using tikz are in standalone mode (I can compile the figures by themselves). Then I use the standalone package in the main document to remove the preamble in the included images. I have the feeling this may be one of the main issues but I'm not sure: Because the preamble of the main document is used instead of the preamble of the included figures, every single time I `\input` a standalone figure file I reload the preamble of the main document (which I mentioned is huge). How can I confirm this is what's happening? Also, how can I speed this up? I thought of creating two versions of the input images, one without the preamble and one with the preamble and input one or the other based on a flag I define at the top of the main document. But since this will be quite some work I thought to ask first.
2. I also thought of having a flag that would determine whether to externalize the figure or just use `\includegraphics` on the compiled one (using tikz externalize), but this would be repeating the functionality of the externalize package so I don't know if it makes much sense. I also think that I may run out of memory?
3. Is there a way to **time** the pdflatex compilation so I have an idea where time is being spent? Is it possible to do profiling on pdflatex?

Comment: I would at first compile in a terminal and look how the log goes along, it normally gives a good idea which pages or code parts take a long time.

Comment: if you use standalone class (not package) to make pdf of your tikz you can include them into your document simply as `\includegraphics` with no trick preamble-mangling

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but this won't work since once we send the book to the publisher they will have to recompile all figures with their protected font type. Also, I think I would run out of memory no?

Comment: well they could re-generate the pdfs (that's all externalize is doing anyway) memory consumption is minimised by doing the tikz separately so I don't understand your out of memory comment.